# How to compare a certain character with another character of a string

Tags: c++

In the following code, I am having trouble comparing specific letters two given strings.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int m, n;
    cin >> m >> n;
    cin.ignore();

    string phrases[m];
    string records[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        getline(cin, phrases[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        getline(cin, records[i]);
    }

    int lowBound;
    sort(phrases, phrases + m);
    int ans = 0;
    bool stillIs;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        lowBound = lower_bound(phrases, phrases + m, records[i]) - phrases;
        if (lowBound == m) {
            continue;
        }
        stillIs = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < records[i].length(); i++) {
            if (records[i][j] == phrases[lowBound][j]) {
                stillIs = false;
            }
        }
        if (stillIs) {
            ans++;
        }
    }

    cout << ans;

    return 0;
}
```

On line 33, if (records[i][j] == phrases[lowBound][j]), it is not giving me an error, but if I run it with this line, nothing happens, but when I comment the if statement out, it works properly, but obviously not giving me the correct answer. Is there any way I can compare these two strings (the second one is larger in size than the first one) to find whether the first one is the start of the second one?

Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated: Be really careful with the combination of `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` and `using namespace std;`. It's really easy to fall into nigh-inscrutable errors by bringing the tens of thousands of identifiers in the C++ Standard Library into conflict with the your code sitting in the global namespace.

Comment: Careful with `string phrases[m];` and `string records[n];`. These are Variable Length Arrays. Your compiler allows them by extension, but many don't. The more immediate threat is a modern `std:":string` can be quite large. `m`s or `n`s in the 10,000-20,000 range could run the program out of stack space, and that can be a really hard problem to detect and debug. Consider using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: You seem to mix iteratortype and int type

Comment: If you are compiling to the brand-spanking new C++ 20 standard, you can call [`std::string::starts_with`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/starts_with) to find if one string starts with the other. Otherwise there are [`std::string::compare`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) overloads that allow you to specify ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are incrementing `i` instead of `j` in the loop at line 32
- You have your test backwards in line 33 - you want to set `stillIs = false` if the characters *don't* match, (i.e., `!=`)

I haven't fully read your code, but those two problems jumped out at me, so see if that sorts it out